# PHP & json_decode - how to get property of object

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-opengraph

**CONTEXT**

I'm using `json_decode` to convert the contents of an Facebook open graph call into a php object.

**EDIT to add code**

My code looks like this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com"),true);
var_dump($json);
```

A `var_dump` of the resulting object looks like this:

```
ARRAY(3) { ["ID"]=> STRING(18) "HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM" ["SHARES"]=> INT(14604317) ["COMMENTS"]=> INT(11300) }
```

**PROBLEM**

I would like to get the 12 from this object. I assumed that `$json->shares` would return 12, but instead it returns null. Any idea what the correct syntax for retrieving the 12 would be?

Comment: Where is `$object` coming from? Your code only shows a `$json` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array doesn't look right. Check out http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com in a browser, notice how the keys and values are all lowercase, not uppercase like you have.

If you really are testing http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com, then this will just work:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com'), true);
echo $array['shares'];
```

This gives me `14604317` which I can see in my browser is the correct result.

Note you have an array, not an object. So use array notation:

Comment: Thanks for the response. This did not work - it still returns ```null```.

Comment: @Sekoul then you have something else going on, update your question and provide more code.

Comment: @Sekoul I added a link showing that this code does work, with the array you show above. If it doesn't work for you, then your array is different and you need to show us what you are _actually_ working with.

Comment: I've added the full code above - I think the version you're testing with is slightly different format: ```'{ "ID" : "HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM", "SHARES" : 12 }'``` versus ```ARRAY(3) { ["ID"]=> STRING(18) "HTTP://EXAMPLE.COM" ["SHARES"]=> INT(14604317) ["COMMENTS"]=> INT(11300) }```

Comment: Your code above still doesn't make any sense. You show a `$json` variable but then try to access `$object`? Where is that coming from?

Comment: my bad - that was left over from before edits. I'm trying to access ```$json->shares``` and ```$json['SHARES']``` as you suggested, but both show null when I do ```var_dump```

Comment: Are you really doing `var_dump($json['SHARES']);` or just `var_dump($json)`?

Comment: Look at `http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com` in a browser. Notice how all the keys are lowercase? How can your array be all uppercase? You still have something else in your code that you aren't showing us.

Comment: Updated my answer. Those two lines of code work perfectly, I just tested them on my computer. If they don't work for you, you aren't showing us the real code or the real array you are working with.

Comment: You got it - the small caps version worked. I think the issue was that on the front end, my CSS styling had ```text-transform: uppercase```, which caused everything to appear in caps...  woe is me. Thanks so much for the help!